# Remove an item from an list if certain condition met in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3, trying to remove an item from a list if a condition is met.

```
list = ["x", "y"]
for item in list:
  if item == "x":
    list.pop()
  print(list) #output should be ["y"]
```

Comment: Use list comprehension: `lst = [i for i in lst if i != 'x']`

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a list while it's being iterated.

Try:

```py
list.remove("x")
```